# PL/SQL Dynamic Loop Value

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

My goal is to keep a table which contains bind values and arguments, which will later be used by dbms_sql. The below pl/sql example is basic, it's purpose is to illustrate the issue I am having with recalling values from prior loop objects.

The table **account_table** holds acccount information

```
CREATE TABLE account_table (account number, name varchar2(100)));

INSERT INTO mytest 
    (account, name) 
VALUES 
    (1 ,'Test');
COMMIT;
```

The table **MYTEST** holds bind information

```
CREATE TABLE mytest (bind_value varchar2(100));

INSERT INTO mytest (bind_value) VALUES ('i.account');
COMMIT;



DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
  v_ret VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (
    SELECT account
    FROM account_table
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
  ) LOOP

    FOR REC IN (
      SELECT *
      FROM mytest
    ) LOOP

      v_sql := 'SELECT ' || rec.bind_value || ' FROM dual';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_ret;

      dbms_output.put_line ('Account: ' || v_ret);
    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I cannot store the name **i.account** and later use the value that object. My idea was to use NDS; but, while the value of **v_sql** looks ok (it will read "Select i.account from dual"), an exception of invalid identifier would be raised on **i.account**. Is there a way to get the value of the object? We are using Oracle 11g2.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to run the `execute immediate` statement? You can just output the value using `dbms_output.put_line('Account: ' || i.account)`, no need for dynamic SQL!

Comment: @Chris Saxon: Yes; however, the end goal isn't to output the value of the loop object, but to use that value within a query using DBMS_SQL. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE was just used to illustrate that i.account is an invalid identifier in the way it was being used; but the value of i.account would be useful in a query, stored in a table, which is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL will not have the context of your PL/SQL block.  You cannot use identifiers that are defined in the PL/SQL block in your dynamic SQL statement.  So you cannot reference `i.account` and reference the loop that you have defined outside of the dynamic SQL statement.  You could, of course, dynamically generate the entire PL/SQL block but dynamic PL/SQL is generally a pretty terrible approach-- it is very hard to get that sort of thing right.

If you are trying to use the value of `i.account`, however, you can do something like

```
v_sql := 'SELECT :1 FROM dual';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
   INTO v_ret
  USING i.account;
```

That doesn't appear to help you, though, if you want to get the string `i.account` from a table.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I guess I need a new approach to this project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you always trying to access the same table with the same where clause, but just looking for a different column each time? If so, you could do this:

```
p_what_I_want := 'ACCOUNT';
--
SELECT decode(p_what_I_want
               ,'ACCOUNT', i.account
               , 'OTHER_THING_1', i.other_thing_1
               , 'OTHER_THING_2', i.other_thing_2
               , 'OTHER_THING_1', i.default_thing) out_thing
INTO l_thing
FROM table;
```

The above statement is not dynamic but returns a different column on demand...

Comment: No, the sql statements are varied each time; but, this approach will prove useful elsewhere.Thanks!